# sizeof not showing the expected output

Tags: c, structure, sizeof, bit-fields

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    uint64_t u[2];
    struct {
        uint64_t a:30;
        uint64_t b:30;
        uint64_t c:30;
        uint64_t d:30;
        uint64_t e:8;
    }x;
} mystruct;

int main()
{
    printf("Size %d\n", sizeof(mystruct));
}
```

I am trying to compile it on 64 bit machine. The expected output was 16 but I am getting 24.
I know some alignment happened here but i am not sure why as the struct x is exactly 16 bytes. 
Can someone explain this. 
Thanks

Comment: You are using bitfields:  K&R page 150: *"Almost everything about bitfields is implementation dependent"*.  Personally I would have omitted the "Almost".

Comment: @cdark they say *almost* because the rest is unspecified ;)

Answer (score 6):

From the C Standard:

> (C99, 6.7.2.1p10) "[...] If insufficient space remains,
>   whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is
>   implementation-defined."

So in your implementation they don't overlap: `a` and `b` members are in one unit, `c` and `d` are in another one unit and `e` is in another one unit: `8 + 8 + 8 = 24`.

Answer (score 6):

For a 64-bit machine, fields `a` and `b` use 60 bits of the first 64-bit value in the struct, `c` and `d` use 60 bits of the next 64-bit value in the struct, and then because `e` is 8 bits it can't fit into the 4 bits left over from that 64-bit value so another 64-bit value is needed.  Thus 8x3 = 24 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

An element of a bit field will never overlap two memory "units" (in your case the memory unit is a 64bits element).

Beside the fact that bitfield implementation are compiler dependant, there is all chances that your bit-field structure is actually stored the following way in memory:

```
struct {
    uint64_t a:30;
    uint64_t b:30;
    uint64_t :4;
    uint64_t c:30;
    uint64_t d:30;
    uint64_t :4;
    uint64_t e:8;
    uint64_t :56;
}x;
```